# Equal fields and dimension

Tags: field-theory, proof-writing, extension-field, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $K \subseteq L$ be fields. Show that K=L if and only if $dim_k  L=1$

I know that I will have to show both directions of the implication.

I'm very new to the topic of fields so I'm still reading and learning about the definitions, propositions, and theorems.

I know that when discussing fields the dimension is equal to the degree though. Will this come in handy?

Any advice of what definitions or theorems or strategies to use would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Let the dimension of $L$ as $K$ vector space be 1. Then any non-zero element $x\in L$  the set $\{1, x\}$ is a linearly dependent set; so we can find $a,b\in K$ such that $a+bx=0$ which implies $x= -\frac ab\in K$. So $L\subset K$.

Comment: Thanks. Will I need to show the forward implication as well? That if K=L then $dim_K L=1$?

Comment: Yes, you have to show every element of $K$ is  multiple of some fixed element of $K$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please? Thank you so much!

Comment: Any element $x$ of $K$, with $x$ regarded as a 'vector', can be written as $x= x.1$, and the $x$ on the rhs is the same now in its  scalar avatar. SO the singleton $\{1\}$ is a basis of $K$ over $K$  proving that the dimension is 1.